# How convert string approximately 300 characters and then showing continuation with [...] after a word break.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on RSS feed. In Rssfeed `<description>` (string) tag suggest using approximately 300 characters and then showing continuation with [...] after a word break.

```
<description>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially [...]</description>
```

Code:

```
 TextWriter.WriteStartElement("item");
 TextWriter.WriteElementString("title", oFeedItem["CommPostSubject"].ToString());
 TextWriter.WriteElementString("description", oFeedItem["CommPostDescription"].
 ToString());
 TextWriter.WriteElementString("link", oFeedItem["CommPostSubjectUrl"].ToString());
 TextWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

How we can do with a string by showing continuation with [...] after a word break?

Comment: I've always found that this curs off the content in an unusual place. If its for a blog or the like of that the convention is to use a hidden break expression in the html. Check out the jump break feature in blogger. This way you always get a meaningful opening paragraph without showing all of your content in list based views etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `extension-method` for `string`s like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions{
        public static string SubText(this System.String str, System.Int32 charCount, System.String continues) {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || str.Length < charCount)
                return str;
            str = str.Substring(0, charCount);
            int i = str.LastIndexOf(" ");
            if (i >= 0)
                str = str.Remove(i);
            str = String.Concat(str, continues);
            return str;
        }
}
```

and call this extension in your code:

```
TextWriter
    .WriteElementString("description", oFeedItem["CommPostDescription"]
    .SubText(300, " [...]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string TextAbstract(string text, int length)
        {
            if (text == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            if (text.Length <= length)
            {
                return text;
            }
            text = text.Substring(0, length);
            text = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf(" "));
            return text + "...";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution:

- Take the first 300 characters
- Find the last space (or other word-breaks)
- Append ellipsis

**code:**

```
var fullText = "Lorem Ipsum....";
var first300 = fullText.SubString(0, 300);
var lastSpace = first300.LastIndexOf(" ");

var summary = string.format("{0}[...]", first300.SubString(0, lastSpace));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail in a malicious case of a large string without spaces?

Comment: Sure, if you expect the chance of 300+ spaces leading any valid text then a simple TrimStart() at the beginning would clear it up.  And it's not meant to be much more than pseudo-code

Answer (score 0):

use

```
string ShorterString = "";
if ( YourLongString.Length > 300 )
{
     ShorterString = YourLongString.SubString ( 0, 300);
     ShorterString = ShorterString.SubString ( 0, ShorterString.LastIndexOf (" " ) + 1) + "...";

}
else { ShorterString = YourLongString; }
```

Comment: that While loop is kind of nasty, especially since string are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

By using the overload of [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx) that takes a startIndex, you can create one less intermediate string.

```
if (inputString.Length > maxlen)
{
    int breakindex = inputString.LastIndexOf(" ", maxlen);
    if (breakindex < 0)
    {
        breakindex = maxlen;
    }
    inputString = s.Substring(0, breakindex) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Cutstring(string s, int min, int max)
{
    string res = "";
    int runto = s.Length;
    if (s.Length > max) runto = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < runto; i++)
    {
        if (i > min)
        {
            if ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] == '_')|| (s[i] == '-'))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        res += s[i];
    }
    if (s.Length > max) res += "...";
    return res;
}
```